# script working manually but not via crontab?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cron

Wondered if anyone had any idea why the following problem is occurring, or had any tips where to look…I can run the shell script manually in ssh, but if I set it up to run in crontab i get the problems below.

Server is:  FreeBSD 8, and I have access to all root permissions

I have a shell script (Bourne) that runs under the “root” permissions using crontab with the following command:

```
* * * * * /data/backups/scripts/server_log_check.sh > /data/backups/logs/cron_logs/server_log_check.sh_cron.log
```

The “server_log_check.sh” script checks to see if “the report server” is running with this command:

```
if ps -xauww | grep -v grep | grep java | grep www > /dev/null
            then 
                            #“reports are running, no need to try to restart it”
            Else
                            /usr/local/etc/rc.d/tomcat55 start     #start report server because it is not running
            Fi
```

The problem is occurring on this line: “`/usr/local/etc/rc.d/tomcat55 start`”, when the script is run using crontab, but if I run the script manually via ssh this line of code runs without a problem, but all the rest of the code in the script executes fine, just not this line.  Allternatively, if I paste this line `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/tomcat55 start` into the ssh command prompt, it runs just fine too.

I changed the “server_log_check.sh” ownership to be “root”, but that didn’t make a difference, and the script "tomcat55" ownership is "www".  The crontab entry is being made under the "Root" profile, so, I assumed there is no problem running a file that is owned by a lessor permission such as "www" has

Do you have any ideas why cron is doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error message, if any, are you getting?

Comment: You have a capital E in the else.. is that a copy and paste error or the actual script?

Comment: no error that I was aware of...the capital "E" is my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following which will add the error to the log file as well:

```
* * * * * /data/backups/scripts/server_log_check.sh > /data/backups/logs/cron_logs/server_log_check.sh_cron.log 2>&1
```

Also change this:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/tomcat55 start
```

to:

```
cd /home/root

nohup /usr/local/etc/rc.d/tomcat55 start &
```

This should create a `nohup.out` in `/home/root`.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for your tip to send the error into the log file.  I found that inside the "tomcat55" script the "chown" command needed to have the full path "/usr/sbin/chown" instead of just "chown" in order for the crontab to run it.  Everything works great!  4 hours yesterday spent...a one minute change you suggested was all I needed!.  P.S, I couldn't get the "nohup" to write anything out, but I guess it doesn't matter now. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked ! The nohup should create a nohup.out in the directory where it was invoked. I guess it does not matter now, but you might need it in the future.